# How to make the reinterpret_cast more safe?

Tags: c++, templates, casting

Let's say we have this function template:

```
template<typename T, typename... Args>
T* creator(const Args&... args)
{
  return new T{args...};
}
```

Now I want to save a couple of pointers to the instantiations of this template in some container. To do this I make the `reinterpret_cast<void*>(creator<type_a, type_b, etc>)`. But when I make the reverse operation, I could to make some check to ensure whether this operation is safe. I.e. whether a (previously saved) pointer to void actually points to a template instantiation which we try to cast to?

Probably there is need to save some kind of a type information too, not only the `void*`. Or something like this.

**EDIT**

Actually this template is a private static member of the class template. Pointers to its instantiations are held in the `std::unordered_map<std::string, void*>`. They are called in another method:

```
template<typename... Args>
T* create(const std::string& id, const Args&... args)
try
{
  return reinterpret_cast<T* (*)(const Args&...)>(_creators.at(id))(args...);
}
catch(...)
{
  return nullptr;
}
```

And here I could to check whether a concrete `_creator`'s instantiation was registered in the `_creators`.

Comment: This seems like a bad design... What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: @Holt, actually to make a creator. I.e., to make the template, which (a) can to accept a variable number of a parameters and (b) constructs an object of the given class.

Comment: @SergeRoussak This does not require a cast to `void*` - If you need to cast it's because you either want to store heterogeneous objects inside a single container, or you want to do dispatch depending on the type. Most of the times, there are cleaner way to do this, but you need to explain what you want to do with these pointers afterward.

Comment: You might want `std::any`...

Comment: @keith, cannot dynamic_cast (target is not pointer or reference to class) -- compiler said.

Comment: @Serge Roussak, don't use `dynamic_cast<void*>` and make sure you are using `dynamic_cast<some_type*>` - with an asterisk.

Comment: @Holt, I try to make a factory and this template is a part of it. I save pointers to instantiations of this template inside of a single container and call them when the fabric need to create an object.

Comment: @keith You cannot `dynamic_cast` from `void*`, you can only `dynamic_cast` between classes from the same class hierarchy (and you need virtual classes).

Comment: @SergeRoussak And what are you doing with the elements inside your containers? Maybe show us a sample code of what you do (the unsafe version).

Comment: A key property of a `void *` is that, on its own, it is associated with no information about the actual type of whatever it points at.    So this question has no answer in standard C++, other than by accessing additional information (stored somewhere else by your program)  that identifies the actual type.

Comment: @Peter, I agree with you completely. But may you explain?

Comment: @Holt, I edited my question.

Comment: @SergeRoussak - if you agree with me, you don't need an explanation from me.

Comment: @Peter, your "So this question has no answer in standard C++, other than by accessing additional information (stored somewhere else by your program) that identifies the actual type" needs explanations, because it contains the "somewhere" word exactly and meant "somehow".

Comment: As Jarod42 suggested, use `std::any` and forget about `void*`

Comment: @SergeRoussak - I did not use "somewhere" when I meant "somehow".   I used "somewhere" in the sense of "some location to be determined by your program", which may be in your program's memory, on a storage device, etc etc.

Comment: Be aware that "**[expr.reinterpret.cast]/8** Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported." At the very least, you may want to store `void (*)()` pointers rather than `void*` pointers.

Comment: Can `std::variant` be used to improve your code?